# Send email on Custom button click?

Tags: apex, email, custom-button, email-template

I was able to implement: OnClick on Custom button to redirect to the Email template page with values filled-in using:

```
location.replace('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Contact.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL={!Case.Id}&template_id=00Xn0000000MYQyXXA&p26=noreply@arnoldjr.com');
```

But is there a way to implment:
OnClick --> Sends an email, gives me an alert message on Screen **Email sent successfully** and redirects back to the Case record detail page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, behind the Custom button, this is perfectly working for me.

> Note that, Only User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for `targetObjectId`

**Code**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js")}
var message = new sforce.SingleEmailMessage(); 

message.targetObjectId = "{!Contact.Id}";
message.toAddresses = "{!Contact.Email}";
message.templateId = "00Xq0000000HwSw"; 
message.whatId = "{!Case.Id}"; 

var result = sforce.connection.sendEmail([message]); 
if(result[0].success == 'true') 
{ 
    alert("Email sent successfully"); 
} else 
{ 
    alert("Sending failed"); 
} 
alert(result);
```

> Refer Partner WSDL, to find the other attributes of SingleEmailMessage

```
<complexType name="SingleEmailMessage">
<complexContent>
<extension base="tns:Email">
<sequence>
<element name="bccAddresses" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="25" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="ccAddresses" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="25" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="charset" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="documentAttachments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:ID"/>
<element name="entityAttachments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:ID"/>
<element name="fileAttachments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:EmailFileAttachment"/>
<element name="htmlBody" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="inReplyTo" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="optOutPolicy" type="tns:SendEmailOptOutPolicy" nillable="true"/>
<element name="orgWideEmailAddressId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tns:ID" nillable="true"/>
<element name="plainTextBody" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="references" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="targetObjectId" type="tns:ID" nillable="true"/>
<element name="templateId" type="tns:ID" nillable="true"/>
<element name="toAddresses" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<element name="treatBodiesAsTemplate" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true"/>
<element name="treatTargetObjectAsRecipient" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true"/>
<element name="whatId" type="tns:ID" nillable="true"/>
</sequence>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement: OnClick --> to send an email?
As the template I am using is a custom Visualforce Email template, I am using this location.redirect by providing required values.

Comment: Send an email to the recipient, i.e, Case record's owner.

Comment: No. This is a standard Salesforce custom button added to the Case object's page layout.

Comment: I have this requirement only to implement via Custom button. Is there a way to config so?

Comment: Can I implement something like:
`(function() { 
var message = new sforce.SingleEmailMessage(); 
message.targetObjectId = "{!Contact.Email}"; 
message.templateId = "00Xn0000000MYQyEAO"; 
message.whatId = "{!Case.Id}"; 
var result = sforce.connection.sendEmail([message]); 
if(result[0].success == 'true') { 
alert("Email sent successfully"); 
} else { 
alert("Sending failed"); 
} 
alert(result); 
}());`

Comment: But I am getting this error:
`{error:
{message:’bad id john.doe@gmail.com’,
statusCode: ‘MALFORMED_ID’, targetObjectId: ‘john.doe@gmail.com’,},
success:’false’,} `

Comment: It should be `toAddresses` but that didn't work either. I got error message saying: `Required field missing: targerObjectId`. When I add this field again, getting the previous error. I am not sure what part I am still missing.

Comment: finally it worked for me, pls find the updated code

Comment: Well, I really really appreciate your help/time. You are just awesome. Take a BOW!